# Confirmação de Email em C#!

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, envio-de-email

Fiz esse formulário que o usuário ao se cadastrar deve receber um email no qual vai ter um link pra que ele confirme o seu email clicando no link, portanto da forma que eu fiz ele n ta recebendo o email de confirmação.
Para isso criei uma classe chamada ServicoEmail:

```
namespace Ebase.EmissorNFeWeb.Servicos
{
      public class ServicoEmail
    {

        public static  async Task  Execute(string Email, string Texto, string Mensagem)
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Email) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Mensagem))
            {
                System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                client.Host = "email-ssl.com.br ";
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("desenvolvimento@ebasesistemas.com.br", "minhasenha");
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.Sender = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("desenvolvimento@ebasesistemas.com.br");
                mail.From = new MailAddress("desenvolvimento@ebasesistemas.com.br");
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(Email, "RECEBEDOR"));
                mail.Subject = "Confirmação de Email";
                mail.Body = "Nome:  " + Email + " <br/> Mensagem : " + Mensagem;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                try
                {
                    client.Send(mail);
                }
                catch (System.Exception erro)
                {
                    //trata erro
                }
                finally
                {
                    mail = null;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

E no register do AccountController coloquei o seguinte:

```
  [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser {
                    NomeCompleto = model.NomeCompleto,
                    UserName = model.Email,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    EmpresaNome = model.EmpresaNome,
                    Telefone = model.Telefone
                };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");


                    string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    await ServicoEmail.Execute(model.Email, "Confirme a sua conta", "Confirme a sua conta clicando <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">AQUI</a>");
                    Session["NomeUsuario"] = AppDB.PreencherUser(model.Email);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return PartialView("_ExperimenteGratis", model);
        }
```

Alguém conseguiria indentificar o que está de errado nisso ai??

Comment: Qual é a exceção que está aparecendo no seu catch?

Comment: Não aparece nenhuma exceção, pois o registro é efetuado com sucesso, porém não recebo o email para confirmar o cadastro!

Comment: Me refiro ao catch no envio de email, pois você não está tratando o erro e seguindo a execução com o finally mesmo no caso de falha.

Comment: você debugou até o catch para ver o erro?

Comment: A solução foi usar o Sendgrid, aprendi a fazer a autenticação, era isso que faltava... dai deu tudo certo